# Scapy show2() packet problem

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to create some scapy layers and want them to adapt their size on the fly. I use the following code:

```
class Foo(Packet):
name = "Testpacket"
fields_desc = [
         ByteField("length", None),
         ByteField("byte2", None),
         ByteField("byte3", None),
         ByteField("byte4", None),
         ByteField("byte5", None),
         ByteField("byte6", None),
         ByteField("byte7", None),
         ByteField("byte8", None),
         ByteField("byte9", None),
         ByteField("byte10", None),
         ByteField("byte11", None) 
         ]     

def post_build(self, p, pay): 
    if self.length is None: 
        if self.byte11 is not None: 
            x = 0xa 
        elif self.byte10 is not None: 
            x = 0x9 
        elif self.byte9 is not None: 
            x = 0x8 
        elif self.byte8 is not None: 
            x = 0x7 
        elif self.byte7 is not None: 
            x = 0x6 
        elif self.byte6 is not None: 
            x = 0x5 
        elif self.byte5 is not None: 
            x = 0x4 
        elif self.byte4 is not None: 
            x = 0x3 
        elif self.byte3 is not None: 
            x = 0x2 
        elif self.byte2 is not None: 
            x = 0x1 
            print "byte2 is set, x is %s"%(x,)
        else: 
            x = 0x0 
    p = p[:0] + struct.pack(">b", x)
    p += pay
    return p
```

When I do the following in my scapy interpreter:
`>>> aa=Foo(); aa.byte2=0x14; aa.show2();`
I get:

```
>>> aa=Foo(); aa.byte2=0x14; aa.show2(); aa.show();
###[ Testpacket ]###
  length= 1
  byte2= None
  byte3= None
  byte4= None
  byte5= None
  byte6= None
  byte7= None
  byte8= None
  byte9= None
  byte10= None
  byte11= None
###[ Testpacket ]###
  length= None
  byte2= 20
  byte3= None
  byte4= None
  byte5= None
  byte6= None
  byte7= None
  byte8= None
  byte9= None
  byte10= None
  byte11= None
```

Now, according to my understanding, show2() should compute the length of the packet etc. In my case, this should set length *and* byte2. Unfortunatelly this is not the case. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have been searching the bug for several hours now, and I'm out of ideas :-S any suggestion would be welcome.

With best regards

Answer (score 2):

Martin, your understanding is mistaken... `.show2()` computes the packet after assembly.  `.show()` is not supposed to calculate the length... for example, with IP...

```
>>> from scapy.all import IP
>>> bar = IP(dst='4.2.2.2')/"Yo mama is ugly.  So ugly.  Aaahhhhhh my eyes"
```

results of `.show2()`...

```
>>> bar.show2()
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4L
  ihl       = 5L
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 65
  id        = 1
  flags     =
  frag      = 0L
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = ip
  chksum    = 0x6b45
  src       = 10.109.61.6
  dst       = 4.2.2.2
  \options   \
###[ Raw ]###
     load      = 'Yo mama is ugly.  So ugly.  Aaahhhhhh my eyes'
>>>
```

results of `.show()`... notice that `ihl`, `len` and `chksum` are `None`..

```
>>> bar.show()
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None  <-------
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = None  <-------
  id        = 1
  flags     =
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = ip
  chksum    = None  <-------
  src       = 10.109.61.6
  dst       = 4.2.2.2
  \options   \
###[ Raw ]###
     load      = 'Yo mama is ugly.  So ugly.  Aaahhhhhh my eyes'
>>>
```

Comment: No, I understood that... the problem might be explaind in a bad way... my problem is that the values are not set in `.show2()`. See my previous code, why is the value of `byte2` not set when I want `show2()`? I mean, I set the value and it isn't appearing, but the value of `show()` is showing me the changed value. When I send the packet, the value of `show2()` is send, so the value of `byte2` is `None`, it should be `20`. That is my problem. Can you help me on this?